# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'p_signals'

Tags: python-3.x, time-series

I am stucked in this error any help please.
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from subprocess import check_output
print(check_output(["ls", "/home/mahmood/apnea-ecg"]).decode("utf8"))
import os
os.listdir("/home/mahmood/apnea-ecg")
import wfdb
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
recordname = "/home/mahmood/apnea-ecg/a04"
record = wfdb.rdsamp(recordname)
record.p_signals
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `wfdb.rdsamp` source code:

`Returns
    -------
    signals : numpy array
        A 2d numpy array storing the physical signals from the record.
    fields : dict
        A dictionary containing several key attributes of the read
        record:
          - fs: The sampling frequency of the record
          - units: The units for each channel
          - sig_name: The signal name for each channel
          - comments: Any comments written in the header`

Thus you get a tuple of 2 elements, signals and fields. 
I would just write:

```
p_signals, _ = wfdb.rdsamp(recordname)
```

Comment: Thanks sir. It works now but if I want to assign this record.p_signals to a variable how can I do that?
like this:


def ECG_Segment(ECG_Signal_file):
    record = wfdb.rdsamp(ECG_Signal_file)
    bfunc = np.asarray(record.p_signals)
    rawECGFunc = []
    for i in range((bfunc.size / 6000)-2):
        rawECGFunc.append(bfunc[i*6000:((i*6000)+18000)])
    return rawECGFunc

Comment: Sorry I might have missed part of the problem. The code in the answer assigns the `record.p_signals` value to the variable `p_signals`, which you can freely rename, obviously (`any_name_i_like, _ = wfdb.rdsamp(recordname)`. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again sir. It is obvious just I want to convert the list to an array like this:
bfunc = np.asarray(record.p_signals) how can I do that using your code?

Comment: Well, there are many ways (hoping that I understood your issue). The simplest one is just to overwrite the `p_signal` variable, e.g. by adding the following to my code: `p_signals = wfdb.rdsamp(p_signals)`.